# How to reset the AdamOptimizer from Tensorflow while training

Tags: python, tensorflow, optimization

We are currently working on a project in which we change a cGAN architecture on Tensorflow to see if we get better results than standard cGANs. Due to the fact that we implement a progressivly growing architecture we would like to reset the AdamOptimizer from Tensorflow after each phase transition. Nonetheless we still did not manage to do so. We tried multiple approaches but either we get the error message "Graph is finalized and cannot be modified" or the parameters do not get reset.

Would be very thankful if somebody could give a hint or a general approach.

Comment: The easiest way would be creating and initializing two optimizer and use the second, when you want to swap them.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to define the optimizer, gather the Adam variables and their initializers. Then, during the training, you can re-initialize the variables by running the initializers.

The following minimal example should point you in the right direction

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 1))

y_hat = tf.layers.Dense(10)(x)
y = 10

loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.squared_difference(y_hat, y))

train = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(loss)

print(tf.all_variables())
adam_vars = [var for var in tf.all_variables() if "adam" in var.name.lower()]
print(adam_vars)
adam_reset = [var.initializer for var in adam_vars]

with tf.Session() as sess:
    # do stuff with your model: train, evaluate, whatever
    # when the reset condition is met, run:
    sess.run(adam_reset)
```